# SED: Insert line above pattern and append the pattern space to it

Tags: design-patterns, insert, sed

In a file i find a pattern I am trying to match. When I find it, I then insert a line above, but what I cannot seem to do is take the pattern space and append it to the line I am trying to insert. Like so:

```
/xxx/ i\inserting this line and &
```

Hoping that "&" will print pattern space like it does with s

Regards and thank in advance
Creigh

Comment: `&` does not print the pattern space. It is a variable that stores the string that matches `regex` in `s/regex/replace/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -er '/.*(xxx).*/s//inserting this line and \1\n&/' file
```

with reference to comments:

```
sed '/public String getFirstName()/s/.*\("[^"]*"\).*/@XmlElement(name=\1)\n&/' file
```

Comment: Not sure what the difference is between my sed and gnu sed is, but I suspect this wont insert the text above my current line address. Right?

Comment: @user1808408 could you give an example of your expected result, I'm guessing that this might be what you require.

Comment: I have a line: public String getFirstName()..  //among others

Comment: sorry pressed enter

I have to add above it 
    @XmlElement(name="first-name")

so the "first-name" is the match I must manipulate, which I get from the method name.

I'm sure this is a common script folks write

Comment: @user1808408 I'm still guessing but I have amended the solution to take into account your comments.

Comment: Yes, I see what you were doing. I had to modify it to look like this
`sed '/public String getFirstName()/ s/public [A-Za-z0-9]* \([A-Za-z0-9]*\).*/@XmlElement(name=\1)\n\t&/'` 
because I wasnt sure why you included a grouping \("[^"]*"\). To me that grouping had no inverted comas. It worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for your help @potong. I will mark this as the answer, but for anyone reading this see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13291465/1808408) for my efforts as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sed can get at things you `i` or `a`. You could do it by piping the results into a second sed, or if you're using GNU sed, you could do it like this:

```
sed '/xxx/ s//cat file_to_insert | head -c-1; echo " &"/e' infile
```

Assuming what you want to insert is in `infile`. The `e` flag to the substitution executes the text in pattern space with `/bin/sh`, the result then replaces the command. Depending on the size of your input and what `/bin/sh` is linked to, this may be inefficient.

Here's one way to do it with two invocations of sed:

```
<infile sed '/xxx/i\inserting this line and' | sed 'N; /\nxxx/! {P; D}; s/\n/ /'
```

Comment: This would be part of a bigger sed script, so I'm not sure I can pipe into another sed just then. Would you be able to give an example given that this is a .sed script?

Comment: @user1808408: The second solution can't be put into one .sed file. Use the `/e` solution if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a solution myself as well. In this similar scenario I have a public class line

```
public class SomeStatusCode extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
```

and I want to add an @XmlRootElement annotation above that. In a .sed file I have the following

```
/public class [A-Za-z0-9]* .*/ {
        h
        s/public class \([A-Za-z0-9]*\) .*/\1")/    
        s/^/@Xml RootElement(name = "/
        p
        x
}
```

and the outcome is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SOME_STATUS_CODE")
@Xml RootElement(name = "SomeStatusCode")
public class SomeStatusCode extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
```

So in the end I have the desired outcome of inserting a line above my line with content from that line. (Hope that makes sense?)

Comment: Now we know what you are actually trying to achieve. These information should be included in the question in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer in the beginning, but if I had this info I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. What I was trying to achieve was to insert pattern space to the `i` and à`, which is the name of the post. Only after getting some ideas after reading @potong's posts did I change tack and try something else.